# NPVariant string returned from NPAPI/NPRuntime plugin has extra garbage in it

Tags: javascript, npapi, npruntime

Here's what I am trying to do from javascript:

```
var result;
result = document.myplugin.GetClientName();
document.write(result);
```

"GetClientName" should return a NPVariant to the browser with a string.  I am getting my output with garbage appended to the end.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Umm... do it correctly?  You haven't provided any sample code, nor have you explained how you are allocating your NPVariant; that makes it really hard to help you, my friend.

Basically you just need to create an NPVariant, allocate enough memory for it using [NPN_MemAlloc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Memory), and assign the pointer to the UTF8Characters field of the [NPString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPString) inside the NPVariant union and the length to the UTF8Length.

Make sure that you allocate the memory and copy your string over; if you're trying to pass in memory from a std::string or something it's likely getting released before you use it, which could easily cause issues. Also remember to allocate an extra byte at the end of the string for a NULL character -- remember that C strings are NULL terminated, and while the NPAPI spec says that you just need to set the UTF8Length, I've still seen cases where Firefox in particular expects a NULL terminated string and behaves oddly if you don't give it one.

If you want to take this route, you may find this blog post helpful:

- [Memory Management in NPAPI](http://npapi.com/memory)

However, might I suggest a simpler route?  Writing a NPAPI plugin is not a simple thing, and it takes a lot of experience and research to do it well and securely. If you use [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) you can write NPAPI plugins on a C++ framework that already does all of this for you and lets you use normal C++ STL datatypes, works on multiple platforms, and generally saves you a ton of time and hassle.

For a little information on the approach used by FireBreath with scripting, see [my blog post on the subject](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/12/cross-browser-scripting-part-one/).

Comment: setting UTF8 length solved this :) Thnx taxilian..ur posts hv already done much help :)